# Monitoring thread termination in epoll loop

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads

In linux, how does one generate an event to break out a select / poll / epoll loop on thread termination? Processes have a `pidfd` and `SIGCHILD`. Is there something similar for threads?

Edit: this is to directly monitor the thread termination event.

Answer (score 2):

Well the most obvious solution, that comes to mind, is that one of the file descriptors being polled/selected for would be a very special file descriptor, that's reserved for that particular purpose. When you want to "break out" of the select/poll/epoll you simply need to make the appropriate arrangements for this, very special, file descriptor to become available for reading, and this will make it happen.

After select/poll/epoll returns you'll check that file descriptor, just like you would check any other one, and proceed according to whatever should happen in that event. So the only remaining part of this question is what kind of a very special file descriptor would this be?

Well, since you tagged your question with `linux`, you have many Linux-specific options to choose from.

You can turn off native signal handling in your process, and [create a signal file descriptor](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html). Then a sent signal to the process translates to the signal file descriptor becoming available for reading, and reading from it, as documented in the manual page, tells you that the signal has been received.

An [event file descriptor](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html) could be another option, this one's more suitable for different threads in the same process notifying each other.

Both event and signal file descriptors are eminently pollable/selectable. And there's always the old-school approach of creating a `pipe()`, selecting/polling the read end of the pipe, and writing to the write end of the pipe to effect the notification.

Comment: There's also pidfd.

Comment: I must appologies. I forgot the word "on thread termination" in my question

Comment: Well, what does "on thread termination" mean? If the thread has terminated it can't be in any select/poll loop, by definition. In any case, thread terminations don't happen randomly. The only way for a thread to terminate is to return from the thread function, or throw an exception. Both of these possibilities are easily controlled, so you can do whatever you want before a thread returns from its thread function, and wrap the whole/thing in a try/catch block to catch exceptions that would terminate the thread.